# What does a file-like object's `write` method return?

Tags: python, file, io

Python's built-in `open` function returns a "file-like object".  These file objects  can be obtained in other ways as well, and may not actually represent files.

I haven't been able to find what I want to know about these.

https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object states that all file objects all have 1 thing in common: they expose "a file-oriented API".  But I can't find any documentation about this api.

A file object's `write` method seems to return an integer, but what does it represent?  Is the return value guaranteed to be an integer?  What methods and properties are file objects guaranteed to have?

Comment: I believe it returns the number of bytes written, you could look at the documentation for `write` to verify. But I don't know of any documentation specifically for generic file-like objects.

Comment: I was never able to find any documentation for `write` in the anywhere in the Python/C API Reference Manual.  However, after your comment, I decided to try again, and looked through the The Python Tutorial this time.   I was able to find a little documentation about `write` and what it returns in The Python Tutorial, here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects .  (It says it "returns the number of characters written".)

Answer (score 2):

People are so unlikely to *use* the return value of `write` that I wouldn't be surprised if any particular file-like object just returned `None`. That said, there is something resembling a spec.

The behavior a file-like object's methods should provide is documented in the [`io` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#class-hierarchy), under the abstract base classes. While many file-like objects will not be instances of those ABCs, and many file-like objects will not provide all methods in the nearest ABC, methods they *do* provide should match the ABC docs.

For a binary file-like object, `write` should return the number of bytes written, as documented under [`RawIOBase.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.write).

For a text file-like object, `write` should return the number of characters written, as documented under [`TextIOBase.write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write).